# check value containing words implode / different array with array intersect

Tags: php, arrays, implode, array-intersect

I wanted to check to enter data into the database.Checks are as follows

```
$implode1 = "cat, dog, chicken";

$implode2 = "cow, goat, cat";
```

If the cat in the variable `$implode1` is also contained in the variable `$implode2`, it should display a warning message. How to code for the above problem?

Help me please :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$intersaction = array_intersect(array("cat", "dog", "chicken"), 
                                array("cat", "cow", "goat")    );

if (isset($intersaction["cat"])) {....}
```

Function is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)